# EnableViewState causing loss of value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, viewstate

Using vb.net 4.5 and Telerik 2017.2.711.45 (Q2)
I am trying to get radgrid filter expressions and a public string variable to persist across postbacks.

With `EnableViewState=FALSE`, radgrid filter expressions **do not** persist through postback, however a public string variable (stringVar) **does** persist.

When I set `EnableViewState=TRUE` the filter expressions in radgrid **do** persist, however it causes stringVar to **not** persist.

From my understanding of ViewState, it makes no sense that setting `EnableViewState=TRUE` would cause stringVar to not persist across postbacks. I would love to know why this is occurring and what I could do to resolve this.

**EDIT:**
The highlighted Line is where an error would be thrown because ReportTitle no longer has a value.

```
Partial Class displayxslgrid
    Public ReportTitle As String
    Public ReportsDB As reportDataBase
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Page.EnableViewState = True
        Reports = New reportDataBase.Global_Functions(System.Web.HttpContext.Current)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.NeedDataSource
        Call BindRadGrid1()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemCommand
        Dim strReportTitle As String

        Select Case e.CommandName
            Case RadGrid.ExportToExcelCommandName, RadGrid.ExportToWordCommandName, RadGrid.ExportToCsvCommandName
```

> strReportTitle = ReportTitle.Trim

```
        End Select

    End Sub

    Public Sub BindRadGrid1()
        Dim strReportTitle As String
        Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

        ReportTitle = dt.Rows(0).Item("ReportTitle")
        strReportTitle = dt.Rows(0).Item("ReportTitle").ToString
        'RadGrid1 Data source gets set here along with other stuff

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Using view state is normal, and Telerik controls need it to preserve their values across post-backs.  A public string property on your page class should not persist, and should be set/calculated every time.  If you absolutely need something like that to persist, save the value in a hidden server control, or have it in the QueryString of the URL.

Comment: The hidden field is a smart solution and at this point I think that is what I will use, however I am still curious that without viewstate being enabled, the string persists. Any idea why enabling view state would cause it to not persist? Does it fire any additional events that could cause it to lose its value?

Comment: Not persisting would be the reasonable behavior, I'm not sure why/how it could persist off the top of my head.  Can you post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, that that variable was not truly *persisting*.  It was getting its value from the bindradgrid1. When `EnableViewState=True` the need data source event is not fired, therefore the bindradgrid1 is not called and the variable does not get a value. Simple fix was adding a bindradgrid1() in the item command sub so that even with `EnableViewState=True`, bindradgrid1() will still get called. Thanks for all who helped.